# "Out of Stock" Greyed Out in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, inventory, out-of-stock

I have several products in Magento 2 that were imported from Magento 1.7. I added to them color swatches and I turned inventory on. Only one of the products is displayed on the front-end as expected. The rest are shown as "Out of Stock".

The parent product is set to "In Stock":

[image]

And all child products (corresponding with each color) have quantity set to a positive number:

[image]

And yet "Stock Availability" drop-down list is greyed out (disabled) and set to "Out of Stock".

How can I unlock that combo and set it to "In Stock"?

Additionally, if I go through the wizard for Configurations and set product quantities:

[image]

they show up properly in the summary table:

[image]

but as soon as I save the parent product, quantity information is lost and reset to what it has been set to in each of the children products before:

[image]

and if I remove child products and create configurations for color swatches with quantities set for each individual child product from scratch and save changes in the main product, quantity information is lost:

[image]

Comment: I ran the reindexer and cleared all static files but it didn't help.

Comment: Are the products enabled ? Visible ? Included in the right store/website/view ?

Comment: I have double checked and they are all "Online".Parent products' visibility is set to "Catalog, Search" and children's to "Not Visible Individually". I set Magento to single store mode.

Comment: It's not a proper solution, but as a workaround, I found out, you can edit the `<select>` tag in Chrome's inspector to remove `disabled` attribute. After that, you can change the value to "In Stock" and successfully save the product.